# What Windows C++ IDEs support the new C++0X standard?

Tags: c++, windows, ide, c++11

What are excellent C++ IDE options that support the new standard c++0x (windows os friendly) besides visual .net 2010 (the beta is way too slow/clunky)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not supporting the full C++0x standard, much of the TR1 stuff is included in the [SP1 update to Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en). The SP1 update includes the [feature pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/04/07/visual-c-2008-feature-pack-released.aspx) that was released last year.

Answer (score 2):

Now, two years after the question was asked, VisualStudio 2010 supports the following core language features.

1. Lambda functions
2. Rvalue references (move semantics and perfect forwarding).
3. type inference (`auto` and `decltype`)
4. `nullptr`
5. Trailing return type specification `auto f() -> int`
6. `static_assert`

Comment: Thanks, time flies when you're coding in languages outside of c++

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there are few compilers that support the C++0x spec. Specifically, g++ does not come near yet, and there won't be any FOSS IDEs that fully support C++0X until g++ does.

Comment: Yeah some friends at work suggested Netbeans with gcc and cygwin but we agreed that g++ isn't there yet